# HTML tags <b></b> lost during receiving data from another Activity (ANDROID) putExtra getStringExtra

Tags: android, html, xml, android-activity, tags

Hello I share some strings from strings.xml between 2 activities. In first one I have code like :

```
 public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.shops_id:
                intent = new Intent(this, TitleContent.class);
                intent.putExtra("content", getString(R.string.shop_content));
                startActivity(intent);
                break; 
        }
    }
```

In second one I'm receiving data like :

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String content1 = intent.getStringExtra("content");
TextView content  =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contentID); 

        if(content1!=null){

            content.setText(content1);
        }
```

XML looks like :

```
<resources>

    <string name="shop_content"><b>bold content</b></string>

</resources>
```

Problem is that during sharing data html tags are lost. I try to use getText instead of getString but it doesn't work. In receiving activity I try to use to `.setText(Html.fromHtml(somestring));` but it doesn;t work either.

Comment: I think that they are lost not between activities, but when you get it from the resources here: `intent.putExtra("content", getString(R.string.shop_content));`. Have you checked what does `getString(R.string.shop_content)` return you?

Comment: or you can make them bold in your code also. have you tried that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is that during sharing data html tags are lost

When reading in a string resource, if you have basic HTML tags, those will be interpreted and applied to the result. However, that only works if you use `getResources().getText(R.string.shop_content)` instead of `getString()`, and if you use `getCharSequenceExtra()` instead of `getStringExtra()`.

Or, pass `R.string.shop_content` as an `int` extra, so the second activity can use `setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("content"))`.

(BTW, it is a good idea to define extra keys as constants, such as `static final String EXTRA_CONTENT="content"`, so that both activities are using the same key)

Comment: If I'm sharing information between more than 2 activities I should define this static final String for all activities or just in one and use import ?

Comment: @Fuk: Just one. I usually define them on the activity that is receiving the extras; in your case, you may just need to pick some class.